# Javascript: wrapping class property assignment in parentheses

Tags: javascript, class, properties, grouping, operator-keyword

I came across a code where class property assignments are wrapped in the grouping operator and I can't figure out the purpose of it. Is there a reason behind or it's just the way someone likes to write their code?

Also what is the advantage of using !1 instead of false?

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        (this.width = 200),
        (this.height = 300),
        (this.isOpen = !1),
        this.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like (badly) minified code. Nobody should write their code that way.

Comment: The grouping operator is necessary because they chose to use commas instead of semicolons. Don't do that :-)